# Correct way to malloc space for a string and then insert characters into that space?

Tags: c

I have two strings, str1 and str2. I want the concatenation of them on a space in the heap. I malloc space for them using:

```
char *concat = (char*) malloc(strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1);
```

Can I just do:

```
strcat(concat, str1);
strcat(concat, str2);
```

And concat will give me the place on the heap with the two strings concatted? I am asking because it seems that strcat would actually add the str1 to the end of the space allocated using malloc. Is this correct? So, then, str1 would appear at position strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1.

The reason that I am asking is that I am using the method above, but I am getting an error in valgrind:
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What `strcat(dest, src)` actually does is search for the a null byte starting at `dest` and going forward, and then write the `src` string there.

After `malloc`, the contents of memory are undefined, so your current code could do any number of things, most of them incorrect.  If you do `concat[0] = 0` before the `strcat`'s, then your code works but will have to search for the length of `str1` three times -- once for `strlen`, again for the first `strcat`, and last for the second `strcat`.

Instead though, I recommend using `memcpy:`

```
size_t len1 = strlen(str1), len2 = strlen(str2);
char *concat = (char*) malloc(len1 + len2 + 1);

memcpy(concat, str1, len1);
memcpy(concat+len1, str2, len2+1);
```

This takes advantage of the fact that you know from the start where you want the bytes of both strings to go, and how many there are.

Comment: +1 Definitely a very good way to do it.  I'd probably use `memmove()` rather than `memcpy()` because, although `memcpy()` is safe in this situation, it is not always safe but `memmove()` is always safe.

Comment: Don't use `memmove` here; it's confusing. Any usage of `memmove` should serve to document that you're doing something very different and unusual. If I saw `memmove` here I'd spend a minute or two trying to figure out why the #*$@ someone used it and if anything fishy was going on...

Answer (score 6):

You want to do a strcpy and then a strcat:

```
strcpy(concat, str1);
strcat(concat, str2);
```

strcat relies on there being a null terminator ('\0') to know where to begin. If you just malloc and strcat, it's going to do some nasty things.

And no, neither strcpy nor strcat will do any kind of implicit allocation or reallocation.

Answer (score 5):

I would personally do the following:

```
size_t length = strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1;
char *concat = malloc(sizeof(char) * length);

if(concat == NULL)
{
    // error
}

snprintf(concat, length, "%s%s", str1, str2);
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the error check.  `snprintf()` is often a good solution, though it borders on overkill here.

Comment: Don't use `strlen` to compute length. Use `length=snprintf(0,0,"%s%s",str1,str2);` Or just use `asprintf` (and be sure to include your own version - it's a trivial wrapper around `snprintf` - for systems which don't include this GNU extension).

Comment: Justification of R's comment above by himself here (must read to understand the advice): http://stackoverflow.com/a/5615561/340236