# malloc and free in recursive functions

Tags: c, pointers, recursion

I have some code for you and hope someone can tell me, what I'm getting wrong. Currently I'm porting my programming puzzles to other programming languages, to just get some hands on.

The code abstraction in C (updated):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
const char *dummy = "1234567890";
const char* inlet = "_";

void dosomething(int c, char* s){
  printf("%s\n", s);
  if (c < 10) {
    char *ns = malloc(sizeof(char)*11);
    strncpy(ns, s, c-1);
    strncat(ns, inlet, 1);
    strcat(ns, &s[c]);
    dosomething(c+1, ns);
    //free(ns);
  }
}

void main() {
  for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    char *s = malloc(sizeof(char)*11);
    strcpy(s, dummy);
    dosomething(1, s);
    free(s);
  }
}
```

The code runs just fine, until I uncomment the free() call in the dosomething() method. And that is what I don't understand right. As I see it, there is absolutely no problem in freeing the memory, as it is no longer used after returning from the recursive call, but programm output tells something different.

Output without free is as expected:

```
...
1_34567890
1_34567890
...
```

With the second free, only one result is made, than the program stops with :

```
*** Error in `./a.out': malloc(): memory corruption (fast): 0x000000000164e0d0 ***
Abgebrochen (Speicherabzug geschrieben)
```

Update: 
I changed the code according to the comments and answers, but the problem still exists. Allocating more memory with malloc does not prevent the memory error, if the free() call inside the dosomething() method is incommented. Output is generated correctly for the first iteration of the recursion, the second shows different results, the third as well and then the program fails (see the new printf on top of the function for the new results:

Output:

```
1234567890
_234567890
__34567890
___4567890
____567890
_____67890
______7890
_______890
________90
_________0
1234567890
@@J_234567890
@@J_J_234567890
@@J__J_234567890
@@J___J_234567890
@@J___J_234567890
@@J___J_234567890
@@J____J_234567890
@@J____J_234567890
@@J_____0__234567890
1234567890
@@J_234567890
@@J_J_234567890
@@J__J_234567890
@@J___J_234567890
@@J___J_234567890
@@J___J_234567890
@@J____J_234567890
@@J____J_234567890
@@J_____0__234567890__234567890
*** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00000000014a4130 ***
Abgebrochen (Speicherabzug geschrieben)
```

Can anyone please explain to me, what I'm blinking at?

Update2:
@Michi and @MichaelWalz have worked out the point. It is a combination between using malloc - thus working with garbage in the memory after the first iteration (printing the memory adresses along with the strings shows that pretty neat), and using strcat on that.

Using strcat on not initialized memory will append the string in memory to the next "\0" character found after the pointer in memory. If the memory is not initialized, this can be far out of bounds of that string.

Thank you guys!

Working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
const char *dummy = "1234567890";
const char* inlet = "_";

void dosomething(int c, char* s){
  printf("%p %s\n", s, s);
  if (c < 10) {
    //char *ns = malloc(sizeof(char)*11);
    char *ns = calloc(11, sizeof(char));
    strncpy(ns, s, c);
    strncat(ns, inlet, 1);
    strncat(ns, &s[c+1],10-c);
    dosomething(c+1, ns);
    free(ns);
  }
}

void main() {
  for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    //char *s = malloc(sizeof(char)*11);
    char *s = calloc(11, sizeof(char));
    strcpy(s, dummy);
    dosomething(0, s);
    free(s);
  }
}
```

Comment: The variable `dummy` points to the first element of an array containing *eleven* characters.

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C!

Comment: Why you need assignment in `ns = strcat( ns, &s[2] )`? Only `strcat` is enough - see function description. Also `&s[2]` is same as `s + 2` (I found it shorter syntax).

Comment: You forgot to `free` inside `dosomething`; consider using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`)

Comment: @i486: `&a[i]` is more clear if you really have an array. Quite some coding standards (Ue.g. MISRA) forbit explicit pointer arithmethic syntax.

Comment: It's `int main`, not `void main`. This is C, not Java.

Comment: That still does not solve the problem. Using free and everything is messed up here.

Comment: change `malloc(sizeof(char)*11);` to `malloc(11);`, because `sizeof(char)==1` which means that your code looks like this: `malloc(1 * 11)`

Comment: Changing the code displayed in the question is not good style; it renders the answers already given here non-sensical.

Comment: `Allocating more memory with malloc does not prevent the memory error` This is why you should not allocate less memory at the codding time. In future when you code something just give it more memory, like `malloc(512)`. Run you program into a debugger and use a memory check tool and if every thing is ok resize `malloc` to desired size. You will find your problems faster. Function like `strcat` and `strcpy` always are tricky if you dont pay attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard code smell, which has not yet been addressed by any answer:

```
strncpy( char *dest, const char *src, size_t count )
```

This function has two rather unexpected features that many (most?) programmers are not aware of:

- If the copied string is shorter than `count`, `dest` is filled up with zero bytes. (That's usually not a problem.)

But:

- If the copied string (including the terminating zero byte) is longer than `count`, **`dest` will not be zero-terminated**.

---

After looking into your program flow, I see my code smell confirmed:

On the first call to `dosomething()`, `c` is 1, and the contents of `ns` (which points to freshly `malloc()`ed memory) are indeterminate:

```
strncpy(ns, s, c-1);
```

This copies zero bytes, *including **no** terminating zero bytes*. `ns` is still pointing to wholly indeterminate contents. Most importantly, there is no guarantee that there *will* be a zero byte in the memory allocated.

For this reason,

```
strncat(ns, inlet, 1);
```

this is then undefined behaviour.

Due to the aforementioned effect on overflow, always assert that `dest[count - 1] == '\0'` before proceeding.

Comment: @BeowulfOF: Thanks for accepting my answer. Note the edit -- I didn't really think it through when calling `strncpy()` useless. You can easily check it for success, due to the *other* side effect.

Comment: @DevSolar *"Instead of using calloc() as suggested elsewhere (which would be zero-initializing all the memory), I would recommend setting ns[0] = '\0' after the malloc()"*. This will introduce the same bug starting from first recursive call to `dosomething()`

Comment: @rootkea: I don't see that. How do you figure?

Comment: Starting from first recursive call `c` will grow from `2 to 9` overwriting your `ns[0] = '\0'` by `strncpy(ns, s, c-1);`

Comment: @DevSolar If you still want to avoid using `calloc` and want to stick with `malloc` then you can say `ns[c-1] = '\0';` after `strncpy(ns, s, c-1);` and before `strncat(ns, inlet, 1);`

Comment: @rootkea: I have no preference to what exactly the OP does to fix the issues. I was just here to point out the pitfalls of `strncpy()`. ;-) Thanks for the heads-up, though.

Answer (score 9):

The reason is because the *malloc* function allocates 10 characters while 11 are needed (ending `\0`).

While this is implementation dependent, it is likely the *malloc* function, to be efficient, uses some bytes  within and besides the allocated area to set some internal information. After this internal area has been altered (one char too much), *free* may use these bytes and the final result is undefined behavior.

Anyway, altering or even reading an array out of bounds *is* UB.

Better use

```
char *s = malloc(strlen(dummy) + 1);
```

and don't cast the resulting pointer of malloc.

Comment: "The malloc function, to be efficient, uses some bytes ..." not neccessarily. This is a possible implementation detail and not required by the standard. Accessing an array out of bounds is _undefined_ (not _unexpected_) _behaviour_. That's all what is to be said.

Comment: @Olaf agreed, however the reason this part is added is to give a tentative explanation to why the weird behavior *only* happens when *free* is called.

Comment: That is ok, but you should clearly differentiate between standard requirements and implementation details. Also you imply this is always true. In fact, it is not. There are other efficient implementations which do not use in-band data. FYI: that data is likely before the returned address. Reasons are: that way `free` knows where to find it and it is less likely being corrupted, as positive out-of-bounds is much more likely than negative.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have to revert the acceptance, because it seems not to be the problem of the code. See updated question.

Comment: @BeowulfOF Did you fix the two mallocs? Try to print the `s` string at the top of the recursive function.

Comment: I agree with @BeowulfOF. It is correct that we need to allocate 11 bytes, but I still get crashes **even when free is commented out**.

Comment: At least one more issue here: on the very first iteration `c` contains 1. Therefore `strncpy(ns, s, c-1)` copies 0 bytes and leaves the `ns` buffer unchanged. The `ns` buffer therefore contains garbage. Then `strncat(ns, inlet, 1);` yields in undefined bahaviour because `ns` points to uninitialized memory. You may also consider that `strncpy` may leave the destination string without terminating zero if the length to copy is smaller than the length of the source string.

Comment: The only needed thing here is calling [calloc](http://ideone.com/iI4Ewo) instead of `malloc`

Comment: MichaelWalz and Michi are right, it is a problem of garbarge - or uninitialized memory. Don't know which answer to select though ;-)

Comment: BeowulfOF, remember what does strcat is to  join two strings into the destination string, where are those both strings ?...this is why you need here calloc.

Answer (score 5):

`malloc()` doesn't normally initialize the allocated memory.
You should use `memset()` to initialize the allocated memory or
use `calloc()` which does initializes the allocated memory with zeroes.

You should allocate memory for 11 chars(10 + 1 for '\0') and don't
cast the pointer returned by `malloc()`.

On some systems you can configure malloc to initialize memory,
but this is at best a poor debugging aid, you should never count on it.

Comment: Probably this Answer does fix 90%, calloc is needed here and not malloc

Comment: NO, even you you type `malloc(1000);` doesn't fix the problem. The way this code was written only `calloc` fix it. Read more about `strcat`

Comment: malloc(1000) alone won't fix the problem. This is optional but it's always a good idea to avoid the type casting in case of malloc.

Answer (score 4):

```
strncpy(ns, s, c-1);
strncat(ns, inlet, 1);
```

The problem is here.

Whenever you copy `c-1` bytes from `s` to `ns` you never copy terminating `\0` so in the subsequent `strncat` call, the end of `ns` can't be identified (due to the absence of `\0`) and so `_` from inlet may get copied far beyond the allocated `11` bytes of `ns` overwriting the memory.

From `man strncpy`

> Warning: If there is no null byte among the first n bytes of src, the string placed in dest will not be null-terminated.

And that's exactly what happens in each `strncpy(ns, s, c-1);` calls which leads to further memory corruption by `strncat` as `strncat` may find garbage `\0` byte far beyond the `11` bytes of `ns`.

---

As pointed in another answer using `calloc` instead of `malloc` will fill the the buffer pointed by `ns` with `\0` bytes and thus after `strncpy(ns, s, c-1);`, `strncat` will always find terminating `\0` byte just after `c-1` characters of `ns` well within `11` bytes of `ns`

---

Another way is to store `\0` character explicitly at `c-1`th location of `ns` after `strncpy(ns, s, c-1);` and before `strncat(ns, inlet, 1);` sticking with the `malloc`.

Thus working code snippet would be:

```
char *ns = malloc(sizeof(char)*11);
strncpy(ns, s, c-1);
ns[c-1] = '\0';
strncat(ns, inlet, 1);
...
```

Comment: The problem is `malloc` here, [he need calloc instead](http://ideone.com/iI4Ewo), because of `strcat`

Comment: I didn't saw the update, now it's really better (+1)!

Comment: @Michi No. `malloc` is not a problem. *Non-null terminated string because of `strncpy` is the problem*. One can write the same code with `malloc` without any problem. See my updated answer.

Comment: @rootkea In another Answer i commented that too. The way was written is the problem and that's why `calloc` was needed.[Of course you can change it](http://ideone.com/WkowIi)  .

Answer (score 1):

I made some small changes to your code:

1. changed `void main(){}` to `int main(void){}`.
2. changed `int c` argument to `size_t c`, because strncpy expects 
   `size_t`
3. changed `malloc(sizeof(char)*11);` to `calloc(11,1);`
4. commented out the `//free(ns);`.

And I got:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
const char *dummy = "1234567890";
const char* inlet = "_";

void dosomething(size_t c, char* s);

int main(void) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        char *s = calloc(11,1);
        strcpy(s, dummy);
        dosomething(1, s);
        free(s);
    }
}

void dosomething(size_t c, char* s){
    printf("%s\n", s);
    if (c < 10) {
        char *ns = calloc(11,1);
        strncpy(ns, s, c-1);
        strncat(ns, inlet, 1);
        strcat(ns, &s[c]);
        dosomething(c+1, ns);
        free(ns);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solve the issue with strcat/strncat**

First of all, the call to **free** has nothing to do with the problems in your code.

I used **Valgrind** to understand what's happening and the output revealed that there were a conditional jump dependent on uninitialised value:

> ==4722== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
>
> (on the line of strncat)

I did some research and found that **strcat** and **strncat** need the **nul** terminating character to work properly (see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614411/correct-way-to-malloc-space-for-a-string-and-then-insert-characters-into-that-sp), for example). After the call to **malloc** the memory is uninitialised,
moreover the call to **strncpy** doesn't add the terminating char as you always copy (c-1) characters thus not including the null byte (see the [man](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy) page of strncpy, especially the example in the section Notes).  As a consequence, the call to **strncat** may leed to *undefined behaviour*.
To solve this issue, before calling the **strncat** function, we have to set the terminating character correctly, like in the following code snippet:

```
void dosomething(int c, char* s){
  printf("%d %s\n", c, s);
  if (c < 10) {
    char *ns = malloc(sizeof(char)*11);
    if(c-1) strncpy(ns, s, c-1);
    // ----  Set the nul character --- //
    ns[c-1]='\0';        
    // ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- //
    strncat(ns, inlet, 2);
    strcat(ns, &s[c]);
    dosomething(c+1, ns);
    free(ns);
  }
}
```

I also added a check to do the first **strncat** only when you actually have to copy something. It will be also safer to correct the subsequent call to **strcat** (see also the answer from @rootkea) as you are appending too many characters to the **ns** string, going out of the bounds (valgrind doesn't report this).

```
strcat(ns, &s[c]); ---> strncat(ns, &s[c], 10-c);
```